# How to loop in Protractor config file?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am new to JS and Protractor for testing functionalities. I need to include some conditions or loops inside 'Configuration' file of protractor. 
Such as, if I need to check my specs running on 'Windows / Mac' platform and a variable provides these details.

I am expecting something like :

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout : 30000,
    allScriptsTimeout : 30000,
    specs : [  ],
    framework : 'jasmine2',

    ***don't know the syntax, am expecting below line and condition need to work for protractor***
    ***var platform = 'Windows',
    if(platform ==='Windows'){***
    multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'specs': ['spec1.js']
      },
      ***else {***
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'specs': ['spec2.js']
      }],
};
```

Is it possible to validate in Configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`getMultiCapabilities` function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9144494a28dac5a0409de4c5384e933f2d2f8156/spec/getCapabilitiesConf.js#L13):

```
getMultiCapabilities: function() {
    // TODO: check platform and return list of capability objects
},
```

Comment: thanks for pointing to this feature.
Is it possible to call 
getMultiCapabilities: function() {
    // TODO: check platform and return list of capability objects
},
multiple times inside "config" file if I want to check more conditions?